# How can I request a question be reopened if I have less than 3k reputation?

Tags: support, specific-question, reopen-request

A few months ago I rewrote *[How can I blur an image in Windows?](https://superuser.com/q/305633/358766)* so it would meet the site guidelines. (See *[Can any software recommendation question be made on-topic by simply asking "how"?](https://meta.superuser.com/q/12421/358766)*)

I want to vote to have the question re-opened, but I need to earn 3,000 reputation before I can [cast reopen votes](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/close-questions).

**How can I request that a question be reopened if I have less than 3k reputation?**

Comment: Could always drop by in chat and let people know you want it reopened :)

Comment: Making a request like this through meta (like you've done) is one way.

Comment: Questions that are edited while closed are automatically placed into the Reopen queue where the community can cast reopen votes. So in your case, editing the question is sufficient to start the process to reopen the question.

Comment: @Twisty IIRC that only happens if the edit is while it's "on hold" (within first week of close)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, if there's something special you want done that you don't have permission to do through the queues, you can flag the question and explain to a diamond moderator your reasoning for the flag and why you think whatever you flagged should be done.

Sure, this puts more workload on the mods, but if your flag is considered helpful, it was a constructive use of everyone's time (the mod's and yours).

Comment: I've already put 2 flags about [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1275693/response-time-always-late-when-gaming) question and they come back with a message : flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention