# Reviewing questions including "is there a script" about userscripts

Tags: discussion, questions

Tl;Dr: I'm reviewing open questions about *userscripts*. During this review I might suggest edits and flag posts. The intention of this post is to share my current ideas about the edits that I think that might be required to be done to fix questions that looks to be asking to find or recomend a script with special interest in userscripts.

from Wikipedia (links not included)

> A **userscript** (or **user script**) is a program, usually written in JavaScript, for modifying web pages to augment browsing. Uses include adding shortcut buttons and keyboard shortcuts, controlling playback speeds, adding features to sites, and enhancing the browsing history.

---

Questions having "Is there a script" very frequently are not a good fit for most Stack Exhange sites that might welcome questions about **userscripts**, either because they look to be "asking for a recommendation", a "work order", "gime the codez" request, needs more details, be unclear, etc. Specifically the OP is asking for a **userscript**, i.e. to get the old Reedit user interface, instead of asking how to get the old Reedit user interface as happened in [A script for Violent Monkey to revert Reddit's UI?](https://superuser.com/q/1769517/152004).

Besides the X-Y problem, the question didn't show that have tried to search this site. From [my comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1769517/a-script-for-violent-monkey-to-revert-reddits-ui/1769531#comment2755247_1769517) to the above linked question:

> Here are similar questions regarding finding a script [Where can I find an updated Google filter Greasmonkey script?](https://superuser.com/q/147360/152004) , [Looking for greasemonkey script(s) to format numbers (only) in different font](https://superuser.com/q/226508/152004) both from 2010. Another, in this case from the OP, from 2021 : [A script for Violentmonkey to automatically add something to the end of all wikia URLs?](https://superuser.com/q/1660456/152004)

Looking at those questions I noticed that the there might be several similar questions. I plan to review the results from the following search:

["Is there a script" is:question closed:0](https://superuser.com/search?q=%22Is+there+a+script%22+is%3Aquestion+closed%3A0) returns 96 questions

These questions might be "fixed", among other things

- rewording statements including "Is there a script"
- answering them as X-Y problem

---

Currently we have multiple related tags:

[userscript](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/userscript), [javascript](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/javascript), [script](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/script), [greasemonkey](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/greasemonkey), [tampermonkey](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/tampermonkey), [code](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/code)

plus many of the tags included in [Looking for a canonical about troubleshooting issues about using web applications?](https://meta.superuser.com/q/14891/152004)

These tags might help to refine the list of the 96 questions.

On questions not including [userscript](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/userscript) I will suggest to add it.

**Related**

- [Since when are software recommendations off-topic?](https://meta.superuser.com/q/3515/152004)
- [How do I ask a question that may require recommending software?](https://meta.superuser.com/q/5372/152004)
- [Correct way to handle users requesting scripts/formulae?](https://meta.superuser.com/q/11188/152004)
- [What is our stance on questions “Is there any software that can do X or can it be achieved natively with Windows"?](https://meta.superuser.com/q/12401/152004)
- [Can any software recommendation question be made on-topic by simply asking "how"?](https://meta.superuser.com/q/12421/152004)

From Meta Stack Exchange

- [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/289691)